# Stateless Web Api on Azure Service Fabric over https

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-service-fabric

So I have a Web Api hosted on Azure Service Fabric which I would like to expose through https.

First question: is there actually a default certificate for *.cloudapp.azure.com provided by Microsoft similar to the App Service?

If there isn't, how can I have a valid certificate (issued by a well known CA) for a domain I do not own?

In case it is somehow possible I suppose I would need to upload this certificate to the Azure Vault and reference its thumbprint in the service manifest right?

Am I supposed to use the same certificate for securing the cluster and exposing SSL endpoints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no wildcard cert for *.cloudapp.azure.com like there is for *.azurewebsites.net. For SSL you'll have to register your own domain and either CNAME it to your cluster domain (e.g., mycluster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com), or get a static public IP for your load balancer VIP and point your A record to that ([more on public IPs in Azure here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm/)). Then buy a certificate for that domain from your favorite CA.

Once you have a cert, yes you'll store that in Key Vault (make sure you set **-EnabledForDeployment** when you create your Key Vault!) and put that in your cluster ARM template ([to get it installed on your nodes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-security/)).

To use HTTPS, first set up a cert reference in **ApplicationManifest.xml**:

```
<Certificates>
   <EndpointCertificate X509FindValue="<Your Certificate Thumbprint>" Name="Cert1" />
</Certificates>
```

Then set up an EndpointBindindPolicy in the ServiceManifestImport section of **Application Manifest**:

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
...
   <Policies>
      <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint" CertificateRef="Cert1" />
   </Policies>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

And finally, reference the cert in your Endpoint config in **ServiceManifest.xml**:

```
<Endpoints>
  <Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="https" Port="443" CertificateRef="Cert1"/>
</Endpoints>
```

You *can* use the same cert to secure your cluster and provide SSL to users, but I would recommend a different cert so that you're not handing out your server cert to clients for cluster authentication.

EDIT: One could also use [Azure Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/) which supports SSL Offloading. Then it would handle the HTTPS aspects and talk HTTP back to the cluster

Comment: If the service is unable to activate after you do this steps, one of the reasons is when you copy the thumbprint from MMC it copies some invisible symbols at the beginning of the string, just enter it manually or first copy to some simple editor like Notepad

Comment: That tip for going to Azure Application Gateway might be the best I have seen for a while, what a mess when a certificate has to rollover and thumbprints replaced.. Service Fabric does not unregister "netsh http sslcert" from the port and then complains it is already in use.. I will go investigate using Azure Application Gateway for using SSL Offloading

Comment: Multiple certs would require multiple domains, correct?